# ORY Hydra: Can I reuse existing user session?

Tags: authentication, session, oauth-2.0, hydra

The [documentation](https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/implementing-consent/) tells me that I have to display the login UI if hydra tells me to.

"The endpoint handler at /login must not remember previous sessions. This task is solved by ORY Hydra. If the REST API call tells you to show the login ui, you must show it. If the REST API tells you to not show the login ui, you must not show it. Again, do not implement any type of session here."

But why is that? Is there no secure way to reuse a existing user session?

Answer (score 1):

Not if you want to stay compliant with openid connect.

This might be a bit of a read for you :) but ORY documents things about OpenID Connect and very well and you will find a lot of answers here:

https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/oauth2/